# Phantom review count

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, review

Recently I seem to be getting phantom review counts. In other words, the review counter on the menu bar at the top of the screen will have some number like "3" or "5", but when I click on it, the items to review all say "0". This is not a temporary condition due to an item having just disappeared. For example, my review counter is stuck on 3 right now and has been for almost 24 hours straight, even though the Review page shows no items to be reviewed. Here is a screen shot:

[image: review counter bug]

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's currently not possible for us to customize the topbar indicator for every user. As a result, it includes *all* items in the review queues, including ones that aren't available to you specifically. Plus there's a little bit of caching in play.